# Search in User Profiles does not work on localized values at Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, user-profile-service, userprofiles

Search in User Profiles does not work on localized values at Sharepoint 2013

HI! I from Russia and yesterday i was trying to search user profiles by russian. For example, my last name is Мурадов and account name is demo\muradov. I can find myself by searching "demo", "muradov", but I can't find myself by "Мурадов".

[image]
[image]

For search I used Manage User Profiles page from central administration and *UserProfileManager.Search()* method from code.
I decided to figure out, why it happens.

I was decompile *Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles* assembly and saw, that *UserProfileManager.Search()* method is using stored procedure **dbo.proc_Profile_SearchUser**.

[image]
[image]

Manage User Profiles used this procedure too (I checked it with SQL Server Profiler). I used SQL Server profiler and found procedure call, it seem like

```
exec dbo.proc_Profile_SearchUser @partitionID='0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b',@correlationId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',@Term1=N'demo'
```

And it was interesting, because

```
exec dbo.proc_Profile_SearchUser @partitionID='0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b',@correlationId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',@Term1=N'muradov' - retrieved my profile

exec dbo.proc_Profile_SearchUser @partitionID='0c37852b-34d0-418e-91c6-2ac25af4be5b',@correlationId='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',@Term1=N'Мурадов' - my profile not found
```

I open code for **dbo.proc_Profile_SearchUser** and start investigating... and found, that there is a table **dbo.Profile_SearchUserTermStats**, which store my last name as **'???????'**, but table **dbo.Profile_SearchUserTables** - stores my last name as **'Мурадов'**. I changed value '???????' to 'Мурадов' at **dbo.Profile_SearchUserTermStats** table and call **dbo.proc_Profile_SearchUser** - it found with search parameter as 'Мурадов'! *UserProfileManager.Search()* and Manage User Profiles page found me too. But, if I  edit my profile and save it, my russians values will be again as '???????'.

I thought, that problem in collation of SQL Server (it was Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS), and I remove SQLServer and install with collation Cyrillic_General_CI_AS. But all sharepoint databases was created with Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS collation.

Now, I'm stuck. I have no idea what exactly I should do with this and I need help.

**UPD.** I working with Windows Server 2012 Stndart with russian language pack, also I set russian locale in OS (even is I change locale to English (US) - it doesn't help, I tried)

**UPD2.** I found table UserProfileValue which store profile values as sql_variant and when this column convert to nvarchar(4000) - there are right values ('Мурадов')  transform to wrong ('???????'). Even if I try run following:
SELECT 'Мурадов' - result as '??????', but
SELECT N'Мурадов' - result as 'Мурадов'
The problem still not solved.

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but you've committed the cardinal sin of SharePoint. Directly interacting with the database loses official support of your install by MSFT... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057

Comment: @RJCuthbertson I had problem **before** as I touch the database. Now, after I uninstall/install SQL Server, all my changes (and i change only 1 field in row at 1 table) lost and problem still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found bug related with this behavior. Steps to fix them:

1. Open `[dbo].[proc_Profile_SetSearchUserTerms]` procedure
2. Check `@changedValues` declaration (varchar)
3. Alter procedure with

   ```
   DECLARE @changedValues TABLE (PropertyValue nvarchar(255), Direction int)
   ```
4. Be happy.

Comment: A word of caution for future viewers of this question: Directly interacting with the database is not officially supported by Microsoft. DO SO AT YOUR OWN RISK! Or even better, just don't. Just, please don't.

Comment: >>"Just, please don't"
Suggest any other solution, please.